# can't match against case object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Trying to implement a super simple count method for a linked list, but when I try to match the pattern of my case object I get an error.

Here's the code:

```
trait LinkedList[+A] {
  def count = 0
}

case object Leaf extends LinkedList[Nothing]

case class  Node[A](head: A, tail: LinkedList[A]) extends LinkedList[A] {
  override def count: Int = this match {
    case Node(_, t) => 1 + t.count
    case Leaf => 0
  }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
scala> :load LinkedList.scala
Loading LinkedList.scala...
defined trait LinkedList
defined module Leaf
<console>:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Leaf.type
 required: Node[A]
Note: if you intended to match against the class, try `case _: <none>`
           case Leaf => 0
                ^
```

What I don't understand, is that I've always matched case objects like this, but now it doesn't work for some reason... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are matching `this`, which is a `Node`.  A `Leaf` is not a `Node`, so `this` can never be a `Leaf`.  The compiler is basically telling you that the `Leaf` case is never going to happen, so you probably have a bug.

To fix the bug, delete that case.  You don't need it anyway since the leaf case is handled by the default `count` method defined on the trait.  This means that the method should be reduced to the more intuitive:

```
override def count: Int = 1 + tail.count
```

Or move the `count` method up to the trait:

```
trait LinkedList[+A] {
  def count: Int = this match {
    case Node(_, t) => 1 + t.count
    case Leaf => 0
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for moving the count method into the trait.  I'd also recommend making your LInkedList trait sealed if you only intend to have those two implementing case classes/objects.